# How can I imitate the colframe title background behavior in a custom tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

I'd like to make custom `tcolorbox` boxes, but I ran into a snag with the title background.

I know how to draw the frame, but I am not sure how to apply the red background behind the title. I would like to apply it "the `tcolorbox` way" before I start doing it the tikz way.

*Note that the font color of the customized version is already red and must be changed to white.*

The question is best understand in the code itself, so here it is:

Sidenote: I just noticed that the second box is also slightly wider. Hmm that is not good.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Basic Version
\NewDocumentCommand{\ithhint}{ O{} m }{%
\tcbset{colback=white,colframe=red!55!black,boxrule=0.5pt,title={#1},fonttitle=\bfseries}
\begin{tcolorbox}[]
#2
\end{tcolorbox}
}%

% Customized Version
\NewDocumentCommand{\ithnote}{ O{} m }
{
\colorlet{colornote}{red!55!black}
\newtcolorbox[]{ithnotebox}{%
    % Example Frame Start
    empty,% Empty previously set parameters
    title={#1},% use \thetcbcounter to access the ithexample counter text
    % Attaching a box requires an overlay
    attach boxed title to top left,
       % Ensures proper line breaking in longer titles
       minipage boxed title,
    % (boxed title style requires an overlay)
    boxed title style={empty,colframe=red,size=normal,boxsep=0pt,toprule=0pt,top=4pt,left=3mm,right=3mm,overlay={}},
    coltitle=colornote,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=3mm,right=3mm,top=2pt,breakable,pad at break=0mm,
       before upper=\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname0pt, % Use instead of parbox=true. This ensures parskip is inherited by box.
    % Handles box when it exists on one page only
    overlay unbroken={\draw[colornote,rounded corners,line width=.5pt] 
    ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west) --
    ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south east) --
    ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south east) -- ([xshift=-0pt]title.north east) --
    cycle ; },
    % Handles multipage box: first page
    overlay first={\draw[colornote,rounded corners,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: middle page
    overlay middle={\draw[colornote,rounded corners,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: last page
    overlay last={\draw[colornote,rounded corners,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },%
    }
\begin{ithnotebox}
  #2
\end{ithnotebox}\endlist
}

\begin{document}
\ithhint[Hint]{Check this out. How can I customize the hell out of this?}
\ithnote[Note]{I would like to make this box look like the hint box. I will give it a shot with some Latin. \lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: I don't think, it's a good way to define a `\newtcolorbox` inside of a command

Comment: It should not affect the result, however. I prefer it unless you can provide a good argument against it.

Comment: Alright, but I don't understand your question. I don't know what you're after. The different `boxrule` settings are the cause for the different widths.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I've understood the question correctly.

I've applied the `skin=enhancedfirst jigsaw` key and `interior style={fill=colornote}` for the boxed title style.

The different widths were due to different `boxrule` settings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Basic Version
\NewDocumentCommand{\ithhint}{ O{} m }{%
\tcbset{colback=white,colframe=red!55!black,boxrule=0.5pt,title={#1},fonttitle=\bfseries}%
\begin{tcolorbox}
  #2
\end{tcolorbox}
}%

\newtcolorbox{ithnotebox}[1][]{%
    % Example Frame Start
    empty,% Empty previously set parameters
    % Attaching a box requires an overlay
    title={#2},% use \thetcbcounter to access the ithexample counter text,
    attach boxed title to top left,
       % Ensures proper line breaking in longer titles
    minipage boxed title,
       % (boxed title style requires an overlay)
    boxed title style={empty,skin=enhancedfirst jigsaw,colframe=red,size=normal,boxrule=0.5pt,boxsep=0pt,toprule=0pt,top=4pt,left=3mm,right=3mm,overlay={},
      interior style={fill=colornote},
    },
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=3mm,right=3mm,top=2pt,breakable,pad at break=0mm,
    before upper=\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname0pt, % Use instead of parbox=true. This ensures parskip is inherited by box.
    % Handles box when it exists on one page only
    overlay unbroken={\draw[colornote,rounded corners,line width=.5pt] 
      ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west) --
      ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south east) --
      ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south east) -- ([xshift=-0pt]title.north east) --
      cycle ; },
       % Handles multipage box: first page
       overlay first={\draw[colornote,rounded corners,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
       % Handles multipage box: middle page
       overlay middle={\draw[colornote,rounded corners,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
       % Handles multipage box: last page
       overlay last={\draw[colornote,rounded corners,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },%
    #1
    }


% Customized Version
\NewDocumentCommand{\ithnote}{ O{} m }
{
\colorlet{colornote}{red!55!black}
\begin{ithnotebox}[title={#1}]
  #2
\end{ithnotebox}\endlist
}

\begin{document}
\ithhint[Hint]{Check this out. How can I customize the hell out of this?}
\ithnote[Note]{I would like to make this box look like the hint box. I will give it a shot with some Latin. \lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Basic Version
\NewDocumentCommand{\ithhint}{ O{} m }{%
\tcbset{colback=white,colframe=red!55!black,boxrule=0.5pt,title={#1},fonttitle=\bfseries,equal height group=hintnote}%
\begin{tcolorbox}
  #2
\end{tcolorbox}
}%

\newtcolorbox{ithnotebox}[1][]{%
    % Example Frame Start
    empty,% Empty previously set parameters
    % Attaching a box requires an overlay
    %title={#2},% use \thetcbcounter to access the ithexample counter text,
    attach boxed title to top left,
       % Ensures proper line breaking in longer titles
    minipage boxed title,
       % (boxed title style requires an overlay)
    boxed title style={empty,skin=enhancedfirst jigsaw,colframe=colornote,size=normal,boxrule=0.5pt,boxsep=0pt,toprule=0pt,top=4pt,left=3mm,right=3mm,overlay={},
      interior style={fill=colornote},
    },
    boxrule=0.5pt,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=3mm,right=3mm,top=2pt,breakable,pad at break=0mm,
    before upper=\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname0pt, % Use instead of parbox=true. This ensures parskip is inherited by box.
    % Handles box when it exists on one page only
    overlay unbroken={\draw[colornote,rounded corners,line width=.5pt] 
      ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west) --
      ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south east) --
      ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south east) -- ([xshift=-0pt]title.north east) --
      cycle ; },
       % Handles multipage box: first page
       overlay first={\draw[colornote,rounded corners,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
       % Handles multipage box: middle page
       overlay middle={\draw[colornote,rounded corners,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
       % Handles multipage box: last page
       overlay last={\draw[colornote,rounded corners,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },%
       equal height group=hintnote,
    #1
    }


% Customized Version
\NewDocumentCommand{\ithnote}{ O{} m }
{
\colorlet{colornote}{red!55!black}
\begin{ithnotebox}[title={#1}]
  #2
\end{ithnotebox}\endlist
}

\begin{document}
\ithhint[Hint]{Check this out. How can I customize the hell out of this?}
\ithnote[Note]{I would like to make this box look like the hint box. I will give it a shot with some Latin. \lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like the first line of text was cut off…

Comment: @macmadness86: True: I used     `\newtcolorbox{ithnotebox}[2][]{`... which is wrong and was interpreted as using a mandatory argument, it grabbed the `I` from `I would like...`. I corrected the error:  `\newtcolorbox{ithnotebox}[1][]{`...

Comment: I am getting some strange artifacts on the right and left of the title box (with closer inspection, I see them on your output as well). They are small brighter red lines. Do you see them? Do you know why they are there and how I can eliminate them? The box is also slightly higher (which is usually a depth problem solved with a strut, but both "Hint" and "Note" have the same depth.).

Comment: @macmadness86: You introduced the red lines in your first post already. I changed the colour to `colornote` then. The boxes can be made of equal height by putting them into an `equal height group`. (Actually, those issues have nothing to do with your original question,but I addressed them ;-))